# Rotate HDMI Touchscreen on RPi3 (Balena OS)

Tags: display, touchscreen

I’m trying to use the raspberry pi 3 in kisok mode on a 27" hdmi/touchscreen display on portrait mode

I’ve managed to rotate the display with the configuration `BALENA_HOST_CONFIG_display_hdmi_rotate=1` (equivalant to putting `display_hdmi_rotate=1` in `/boot/config.txt`)

but I struggle to rotate the touchscreen inputs.

- should it be possible with configuration in `/boot/config.txt` ? I tried various `lcd_rotate=...` and `display_rotate=...` but it changes nothing
- should I be able to do that with udev rules ? if so how do I figure how to write the rule (selector and transformation matrice) ? and, can I try to apply a rule from the command line without restarting the device ?

Comment: you may have better luck if you do not restrict your search to RPi related websites ... do your search in the Linux realm

Answer (score 1):

Touchscreens use a separate coordinate system which is not synchronized with the underlying display. You should be using [`xinput`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109211/rpi-hid-multitouch-invert-xy) to apply the correct transformation matrix, e.g. for an input device named `Touchscreen` and a 90-degree rotation that would be:

```
xinput set-prop 'Touchscreen' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' '0 -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1'
```

Another option is to redo a calibration on a rotated screen (if the touchscreen comes with a calibration tool) and hope that the calibration process will take care of the orientation.

Although such a command can be run from an `udev` rule, it would be an odd place for it. I would try to make Xorg or the touchscreen driver take the transformation into account via a config file (for Xorg, that would be `xorg.conf`). If that doesn't work, the next best place would be the desktop environment startup script, e.g. the Balena's equivalent of `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.